# Do we really need [rulings]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89210/is-a-ruling-automatically-also-a-houserule) (which is really more about semantics) added the [rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rulings) tag, and the author of that question is also the person who added the description to the tag.

I personally feel that this tag is **far** too generic to be kept as-is; probably at least one third of the questions on this site are about rulings as defined in the tag description.

Remember when [rules](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) was getting put on just about every question without actually telling you anything useful about the question? The [rulings](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rulings) tag is just asking to have that happen again.

Should we keep the tag in its current state? Modify to make it more useful? Just get rid of it?

---

Since we seem to have consensus that the tag is not appropriate, I have removed it from the one question it was on.

Comment: I think the tag has a good description, I just don't think it's good as a tag. Nobody is going to filter on it, like "I am a ruling expert, I want to answer all ruling questions".

Comment: @nvoigt Right, I'm saying that, assuming the description accurately describes what the tag is intended to be about, then that's not a thing we want a tag for.

Comment: I would get rid of it. I didn't realize the full implications when I made that.

Comment: "Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day." -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19754/152515 A description only protects tags that are on at least one question. The mods don't need to do anything, we just need to wait ~5 and a half hours.

Comment: @doppelgreener Ahhh, OK, I thought having a description protected it regardless of how many questions it was on.

Comment: I think a rulings tag could be interesting and distinct from the house-rules tag. Except, a 'rulings' tag would nearly always apply to a question that's mostly opinion based, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Longspeak, yes, I think so.

Comment: @JAMalcolmson - In which case, yeah, we don't need it.

Comment: The tag is now dead, like Batman's parents.